# Excluded maven dependency still showing up

Tags: maven

So this API I'm building uses a dependency (A) that uses javax-validation:validation-api:1.1.0-Final.
Instead I want to make use of the 2.0.1-Final so in the dependency of (A) I added an exclusion.
Next I added the dependency of the version I do want to use...
After that I ran a 'mvn clean install', running mvn dependency:tree shows me I use the correct version of the validation-api in the API.

Problem is however that if I run a mvn dependency:tree in the service where I added my fresh API, the old validation-api still shows up!
I'm sure it already uses the new API because when I go browsing through the dependency sources I see it's already the new pom...

I really don't know what is wrong here...

API POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

API tree:

```
[INFO] com.xxx-api:xxx-api:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
```

Service tree:

```
[INFO] +- com.xxx-api:xxx-api:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.xxx.test:xxx-test:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ....
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
```

Comment: Your example output above is incorrect, after you changed the names of the proprietary artifacts.

Comment: @carlspring you are correct, however, my editing has nothing to do with the issue at hand

Comment: For any future reference:
-> The problem was that parent pom's were explicitly saying the old version should be used.
Solution :-> Define the new version explicitly in the pom of the project i'm working on.

Comment: Avoid to define dependencies in the parent POM.

Comment: The parent `pom.xml` should only contain dependencies defined in a `<dependencyManagement/>` section to avoid such things from happening.

Comment: @ResidentReject : If you want proper recommendations and answers, please provide valid examples. You can still obfuscate things, of course, just be consistent. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this might have solved OP's answer - but running

`mvn clean install`

showed me an updated dependency tree after excluding dependencies.